# Clonar pasta da hospedagem para o bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh

Como faço para clonar uma pasta que esta na minha hospedagem na hostgator para um projeto no BitBucket e após as mudanças subir para a hostgator novamente? É possivel?

Obs: Tenho o acesso ssh da hostgator e consigo acessar o terminal do ssh normalmente.

Comment: Talvez ajude-o: https://gist.github.com/rdeavila/6503795

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de transferir um repositório de um host para o outro é:

1. Clone o repositório que você deseja mover na sua máquina
2. Crie um repositório vazio na outro host, no caso BitBucket
3. Adicione o remote do novo repositório no repositório que você clonou na sua máquina

   git remote -add [nome-remote] [URL]

Lembre-se, já deve existir pelo menos um "origin", já que você clonou o repositório no passo 1, portanto, não use esse nome.

4. Enviei tudo para lá com:

   git push [nome-remote] --all